# How to prevent someone from copying my work?

Tags: copyright, business, graphic-styles, copy-protection

If I were to design a shirt or any type of clothing with a graphic design. And I don't want anyone to steal my design and claim it as their. What should I do to prevent it?

Comment: Ok. And how do you know your design isn't already a copy of something else done by somebody else? You may just be copying somebody else and not even know it? :)

Comment: The same as you would with a precious jewel: put it in a locker and don't show it to anyone.

Answer (score 4):

In the **United States**, you can file a copyright with the Library of Congress (LOC) prior to production:

See https://copyright.gov/

This does *not* prevent anyone copying the *idea*, but it does protect how you've *implemented* that idea (the artwork). It may still be lifted, but if your copyright is on file first at the Library of Congress, you have great footing for any infringement lawsuit you may wish to file.

Note that filing a copyright with the LOC is *not* a requirement. Artwork is copyrighted to the artist(s) the moment it is created. However, by filing with the LOC it's on "official record" as to when and who created the work, making court cases more favorable to the registered owner(s). In fact, in some instances, if your work in on file first with the LOC, you may not even need a civil court for infringement resolution.

Of course, other regions will have different standards and procedures. There are some countries which are notorious for never worrying about copyright infringement concerning the work of others.

All that being posted.. if you don't want something taken, don't put it on the internet. That's really the only way to prevent it unless you have massive funds to file many lawsuits or someone who can constantly send out cease and desist letters.

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer:** This question is verging on a legal question, and since I am not a lawyer, this answer doesn't constitute legal advice.  If you want legal advice hire a lawyer.

You can't really do anything to prevent someone from stealing something you have designed, especially if it's something you are publishing publicly or something you are selling to the general public. If a design can be seen then it can be stolen.

You could always lock your designs away never to see the light of day, but then nobody would ever see them.

If we could stop theft, then the police, lawyers and judges would be out of a job.

However, the law does offer some protection - it's called copyright, and there's nothing you need to do to get it.  Copyright is conferred automatically to the author of an original work when it is created.  Please note: that laws differ by country obviously. In some countries you can register your work for extra protection, such as the USA, but that isn't required here in the UK for example.